# Errors using pyAudio

Tags: python-3.x, alsa, pyaudio

I'm trying to use the pyaudio examples provided on https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#examples.

I have two Raspberry Pis, both of them have the pyAudio installed. One of them can run the examples wihtout any issues, however the other one spits the following error messages when trying to record audio for example:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1438
Expression 'ValidateParameters( inputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_In )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2742
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "audioRecord.py", line 17, in <module>
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 747, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 442, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno Invalid number of channels] -9998
```

I have the following audio configs:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/modules
  0 snd_usb_audio
  1 snd_bcm2835

$ lsusb
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
  Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
  Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
  Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. 
  Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0d8c:000c C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter

$ aplay -l
  **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
  card 0: Set [C-Media USB Headphone Set], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  card 1: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
    Subdevices: 8/8
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
    Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
    Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
    Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
    Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
    Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
    Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
  card 1: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Could you please advise, what can be missing on this second device?

Comment: Those "Unknown"/"Unable"/"Cannot" messages are normal when PortAudio tries to search for all devices. But "channelCount <= maxChans" means that the program uses a wrong format. Which example are you trying to use?

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback!!
I was trying to run the example called "Record".

You're fully right, changing the variable CHANNELS = 2, to 1 resolves the first error message at least, and now I have:

    * recording
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "audioRecord.py", line 24, in <module>
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 605, in read
        return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames)
    IOError: [Errno Input overflowed] -9981

Comment: I'm pretty confused why the other Pi can run the whole script without issues and changing the channels from 2 to 1 or touching the script in any aspects... The hardwares are identical, I've installed the same stuff and made the same config settings (at least to my best knowledge), but obviously something must have ended-up differently on the two devices. 

Any advice on the direction I should take is highly appreciated!!

Comment: Does the other Pi also have the headphone('s mic) as default device?

Comment: Yes, the same is the default device. However I noticed the following difference. The other device (which can play it well) has the following aplay -l:   card 0: Set [C-Media USB Headphone Set], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
    Subdevices: 0/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: So the Subdevices is 0/1 (working) versus 1/1 (not-working). Seems like something is not properly installed here, right?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I thougth that the default device is always 0 (I'm very new to linux...). But after some googling, I found there was no default. Finally removing (renaming) etc/asound.conf solved everything, as now the 0 device is the defult indeed. Thanks a lot CL for leading me to the correct path!!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make the sound device 0 as default.

Comment: How did you do this?